# Cannot re-install application after uninstall on phone

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

i had uninstalled an app im making and tried reinstalling it on my mobile again but I am getting the error below. what could be the reason?

```
 $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.riseapp/com.example.riseapp.MainActivity" -a 
 android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
 Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.riseapp/com.example.riseapp.MainActivity" -a 
 android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
  Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] m 
 cmp=com.example.riseapp/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
 Error: Activity class {com.example.riseapp/com.example.riseapp.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Comment: adb uninstall <your package name> then error should be gone

Comment: @WhatAJerk how can i do this on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

When you uninstall the app from main screen by selecting it that might not remove the app completely from the device.
Try uninstalling it from the `Settings-->Apps-->YourApp-->do uninstall for all users`from the menu on top right.

Solution 2:

Run this command on cmd

`adb shell pm uninstall -k yourpackagename`

Comment: yes i tried looking it up through settings and the package wasn't there. and it still doesn't work @Android_id